# Is there a way to make edge length start from the nodes' borders?

Tags: graphviz, neato

If I have a simple graph with no node decoration, then `len` works fine:

```
digraph {
    A -> { B1,B2,B3 } [len=3]
}
```

[image]

However, if I start adding decorations and titles, then the node in the left has a very short edge

```
digraph {
    node [ style="filled, rounded" fontname="Lato" margin=0.2 ]
    A [ label="Ban điều hành" shape="doubleoctagon" fillcolor="#f4f1de" fontcolor="#000000" ]
    node [ shape="plaintext " fillcolor="#81b29a" fontcolor="#000000" ]
    B1 [ label="Phát triển cộng đồng" ]
    B2 [ label="Nội dung" ]
    B3 [ label="Quản lý hệ thống" ]
    
    A -> { B1,B2,B3 } [len=3]
}
```

[image]

I guess it's because the edge length start from the nodes' centers, not their borders.

Is there a way to make them start from the nodes' borders?

<sub>I opened this on [GraphViz's GitLab](https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues/2137)</sub>

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there is a way so specify "border-to-border" (you might request this here: https://gitlab.com/graphviz/graphviz/-/issues)
But you can increase the **len** value on the short edge.

Comment: this won't work if you need to do `A -> { B1,B2,B3 }`

Comment: Why do you need to use that syntax?

Comment: It would be quicker tbh. For large graphs that can be easier